# How to show that two random variable are independent given a joint distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ to random variables with joint distribution

$$p(0,0)=3/8,\,\,\,p(0,1)=1/8,\,\,\,p(1,0)=1/8,\,\,\,p(1,1)=3/8$$

How to show whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent or dependent variables.

My proof: If we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent then

$$p(0,0)=(p(0))^2=3/8\Longrightarrow p(0)=\sqrt{3/8}$$
$$p(1,1)=(p(1))^2=3/8\Longrightarrow p(1)=\sqrt{3/8}$$

Hence, $p(0,1)=p(0)p(1)=\sqrt{3/8}.\sqrt{3/8}=3/8\neq1/8$ which is a contradiction.

therefore $X$ and $Y$ are dependent variables.

Comment: It is not necessary that $P(x = 0) = P(y=0)$. They are two different random variables.

Comment: @MathLover though here $P(X=0)=\frac12 = P(Y=0)$ so it turns out they do have identical distributions

Comment: @MathLover, yes my mistake. Is there an alternative way to show whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent or dependent variables.

Comment: @Henry, why is $P(X=0)=1/2$?

Comment: @MrDi $P(X=0)=p(0,0)+p(0,1)$

Comment: @Henry yes that's correct. It was a comment on OP's working and hence my mention _not necessary_

Comment: Why $p(0)=1/2\neq\sqrt{3/8}$ ?

Comment: @MrDi As Henry said, $P(0, 0) + P(0, 1) = P(x=0)$. You can similarly find others and check. Or you can assume $P(x = 0) = a, P(x = 1) = 1 - a, P(y = 0) = b, P(y = 1) = 1 - b$.

Comment: @MathLover ,So $X$ and $Y$ are dependent because $p(0,0)=3/8\neq p(x=0).p(y=0)=(p(0,0)+p(0,1)).(p(0,0)+p(1,0))=4/8.4/8$. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: @MrDi yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

- Find $P(X=0)$ and $P(Y=0)$ from the joint distribution
- Compare $P(X=0,Y=0)$ and $P(X=0)\, P(Y=0)$

Comment: So $X$ and $Y$ are dependent because $p(0,0)=3/8\neq p(x=0).p(y=0)=(p(0,0)+p(0,1)).(p(0,0)+p(1,0))=4/8.4/8$?

Comment: @MrDi Yes - precisely that